# How is GCD defined in polynomials with coefficients in finite fields? SageMath claims gcd(xy, x) = 1 in (GF(2^128)/p(x))[y]

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, gcd-and-lcm, sagemath

I am trying to write an algorithm to compute the GCD between polynomials whose coefficients are in the finite field $GF(2^{128})$ modulo $p(x)=x^{128}+x^7+x^2+x+1$. Let's say the polynomials have variable $y$ and we represent the coefficients as polynomials with variable $x$, e.g., `((x^80)*y^2)*(x^90)*y = (x^49 + x^44 + x^43 + x^42)*y^3`.

My intuition is that $gcd(xy, x) = x$, but SageMath instead gives $1$. Is my intuition wrong, or is my code wrong? $gcd(xy, y)$ gives $y$ as expected.

```
K = GF(2**128, name='x', modulus=x^128+x^7+x^2+x+1)
x = K.gen()
S = PolynomialRing(K, 'y')
y = S.gen()
assert gcd(x*y, x) == 1
```

Comment: In the polynomial ring you are working in, greatness is measured by the degree w.r.t $y$, so $x$ and $1$ have the same degree of 0 and are equally great. Furthermore, the coefficients of the polynomials form a field. In this field, $x$ is a unit like any other element (note that $x(-x^{127}-x^6-x-1)=1$ ), and there is no reason for choosing one over the other, except that $1$ is the default choice. What's the gcd of $y+\pi$ and $\frac12$ as polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Therefore, when an algorithm specifies to check whether gcd(a, b) = 1, should I take this to mean "up to multiplication by a constant"?

Comment: As I just edited onto my previous comment: What's the gcd of $y+\pi$ and $\frac12$ as polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Any constant real except for 0?

Comment: @gcdyyxxyy: The constant should be a unit, i.e. have a multiplicative inverse in the ring. If the ring is a field, then it's the case for every non-zero element.

Comment: But consider an algorithm like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Distinct-degree_factorization where the `gcd` of two polynomials is part of the output. Are they referring to a particular 'normalization' of the return value?

Comment: Here your definition of the field $GF(2^{128})$ specifies that $x$ is a root of the polynomial $p(x)$. Therefore $x$ is a constant $\in GF(2^{128})$, and the gcd-calculation is correct as all the non-zero constants are associates. Your confusion likely comes from not having internalizied that declaring the modulus $p(x)$ means that $x$ stops being a variable. This is a common confusion among beginning students of finite fields. Whenever I teach this subject I use $\alpha$ for the zero. Essentially declaring that $\alpha$ is the **coset of $x$ modulo $p(x)$.**

Comment: (cont'd) Consequently I also free up $x$ to be used as an indeterminate again. It takes a while to get used to what is going on, but do spend the effort. Compare with the following. You could similarly define the field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)=\{a+b\sqrt2\in\Bbb{R}\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\}$ by declaring it to be the quotient ring of $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ modulo the polynomial $p(x)=x^2-2$. Undoubtedly your software would then similarly calculate that $\gcd(x,xy)=1$, which is should. Simply because by declaring $x$ to be a root of $x^2-2$ you are essentially saying that $x=\sqrt2$.

Comment: (cont'd) And hopefully you agree that $\gcd(\sqrt2,\sqrt2 y)=1$ in the polynomial ring $K[y]$, $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the answers in the comments, gcd of polynomials is defined as the greatest common divisor $g$ of $a$ and $b$ where $deg(g) \geq deg(h)$ where $h$ is any other common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Since $deg(x) = deg(1) = 0$, both are acceptable gcds.

In the context of the algorithms I was attempting to implement (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Distinct-degree_factorization), it turns out that they wanted the **monic** gcd, where the degree of the leading coefficient is 1, and which should also be unique. This implies the answer to my original question as a special case.